# AWS Lambda Timeout when connecting to Redis Elasticache in same VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, redis, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

Trying to publish from a Lambda function to a Redis Elasticache, but I just continue to get `502 Bad Gateway` responses with the Lambda function timing out.

I have successfully connected to the Elasticache instance using an ECS in the same VPC which leads me to think that the VPC settings for my Lambda are not correct. I tried following this tutorial (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-elasticache-tutorial.html) and have looked at several StackOverflow threads to no avail.

The Lambda Function:

```js
export const publisher = redis.createClient({
  url: XXXXXX, // env var containing the URL which is also used in the ECS server to successfully connect
});

export const handler = async (
  event: AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyWithCognitoAuthorizerEvent
): Promise<AWSLambda.APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  try {
    if (!event.body || !event.pathParameters || !event.pathParameters.channelId)
      return ApiResponse.error(400, {}, new InvalidRequestError());

    const { action, payload } = JSON.parse(event.body) as {
      action: string;
      payload?: { [key: string]: string };
    };

    const { channelId } = event.pathParameters;

    const publishAsync = promisify(publisher.publish).bind(publisher);

    await publishAsync(
      channelId,
      JSON.stringify({
        action,
        payload: payload || {},
      })
    );

    return ApiResponse.success(204);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.error(e);
    return ApiResponse.error();
  }
};
```

In my troubleshooting, I have verified the following in the Lambda functions console:

- The correct role is showing in `Configuration > Permissions`
- The lambda function has access to the VPC (`Configuration > VPCs`), Subnets, and the same SG as the Elasticache instance.
- The SG is allowing all traffic from anywhere.
- It is indeed the Redis connection. Using `console.log` the code stops at this line: `await publishAsync()`

I am sure it is something small, but it is racking my brain!

### Update 1:

Tried adding an error handler to log any issues with the publish in addition to the main `try/catch` block, but it's not logging a thing.

```
publisher.on('error', (e) => {
    Logger.error(e, 'evses-service', 'message-publisher');
  });
```

Also have copied my Elasticache setup:
[image]

And my Elasticache Subnet Group:
[image]

And my Lambda VPC settings:
[image]

And that my Lambda has the right access:
[image]

### Update 2:

Tried to follow the tutorial here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-elasticache-tutorial.html) word for word, but getting the same issue. No logs, just a timeout after 30 seconds. Here is the test code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const redis = require('redis');
const util = require('util');

const client = redis.createClient({
  url: 'rediss://clusterforlambdatest.9nxhfd.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com',
});

client.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const len = 24;

    const randomString = crypto
      .randomBytes(Math.ceil(len / 2))
      .toString('hex') // convert to hexadecimal format
      .slice(0, len)
      .toUpperCase();

    const setAsync = util.promisify(client.set).bind(client);
    const getAsync = util.promisify(client.get).bind(client);

    await setAsync(randomString, 'We set this string bruh!');
    const doc = await getAsync(randomString);

    console.log(`Successfully receieved document ${randomString} with contents: ${doc}`);

    return;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);

    return {
      statusCode: 500,
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: did you try to add an `.on('error', cb)` listener to the redis client to get the real error? Tips: you should keep your publishAsync declaration out of the handler as it is an async version of your redisClient.publish

Comment: Updated original post. Never logs a thing...

Comment: I would check several things: redis ssl configuration (check diffs between redisS connection url and cluster configuration => in-transit encryption + client configuration `tls: {}`), configure the client with a specific retry strategy, check the VPC acls.

Comment: Can you make that an answer? I assumed that AWS would use `rediss://` by default, but since it is only accessible in the VPC, `redis://` was the default.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have timeout, assuming the lambda network is well configured, you should check the following:

- redis SSL configuration: check diffs between redis**S** connection url and cluster configuration (in-transit encryption and client configuration with `tls: {}`)
- configure the client with a specific retry strategy to avoid lambda timeout and catch connection issue
- check VPC acl and security groups

Answer (score 3):

I too was getting the timeout error. I specifically got it when my lambda attempted to *read*/*write* the data to my Redis ElastiCache cluster

In my case I had `TransitEncryptionEnabled: "true"` with `AuthToken: xxxxx` for my redis cluster.

Both my lambda and elastiCache cluster belonged to the same "*private subnet*".
My "*securityGroup*" allowed traffic to flow on all the ports.

Setting option `tls: true` worked for me. This is a mandatory setting if you have encryption at transit enabled.

Here is my code:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import config from "../config";

let options: any = {
 url: `redis://${config.REDIS_HOST}:${config.REDIS_PORT}`,
 password: config.REDIS_PASSWORD,
 socket: { tls: true }
};

const redisClient = createClient(options);
```

Hope this answer is helpful to those who are using Node.Js with "[Node-Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)" dependency in their lambda.

Comment: tls option also solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with my elasticache cluster, here are few findings -

1. Check the number client connections with elasticache and resources used
2. Check VPC subnet and CIDR for nodes security group
3. Try to increase the TTL for lambda and see which service is taking more time to respond Lambda or elasticache